# How to compile a ConTeXt input file that contains PSTricks code?

Tags: pstricks, context

I can compile the following input file using `context filename` unless I un-comment the PSTricks code.

```
\usemodule[pstricks]

\setuphead[title][style={\ss\bfd},
    before={\begingroup},
    after={John Doe, the author\smallskip\currentdate\bigskip\endgroup}]

\starttext

\title{\CONTEXT}



%\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](4,5)
%\psline(0,0)(3,3)
%\end{pspicture}

\stoptext
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the pstricks module is unsupported and was a wrapper around the dvips and ps2pdf shell commands which was therefore not ideal.  You would be better off writing your own script to do this.

See [this thread](http://www.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2009/042372.html).